# WebRTC 5 person conference with recording for playbacks?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc, kurento

I am working on a project for large group broadcasting in WebRTC since it needs to work on iOS and Android devices, I am using Kurento, and iOSWEBRTC cordvoa plugin to build this I am curious if anyone can help improve my plan, or if there is a easier way to achieve this.

We need to have a video/audio conference with 5 people per room, however we need to be able to show that video to large audiences. Now my idea would be use Kurento as a middle-man and capture the streams into .webm files for live playback as the conference is going on.

Is there a better way to achieve this? And how would I playback the webm file as it is being recorded, it needs to update and continue playing as more video is sent, basically a live stream copy of the camera.

I am unsure if I am going the best route but I figured that would reduce the bandwidth from my original idea, I originally was thinking of making it like this:

5 person conference for broadcasters X number of viewers then downloaded those streams however I realize the upload bandwidth requirement would be crazy high, that is why I settled on this idea. Additionally the viewers do not have to see real time like the broadcasters. They need to be able to see and communicate with each other at the same time and the viewers can be a few seconds behind.

TL;DR:

Trying to make a 5 person video conference with video/audio capturing to then live stream it to viewers players. This would allow avoiding of PeerConnection bandwidth limitations. Would this work or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to look into using an SFU or MCU. An MCU is very costly, but multiplexes video streams and sends down a single video stream to all peers, and can also record that stream. An SFU is a single point of receipt of all streams, and selectively forwards them to clients. It could record off individual streams and then you could do post-processing to make a single recording out of the multiple recorded streams. A mesh network of connections really doesn't work for this use case.

Comment: Any preferred frameworks? I need something quickly to deploy.

Comment: @Austin Check our [kurento-room](https://github.com/kurento/kurento-room) project. You should be up and running with that in no time! Also, you can add server-side mixing, but that comes at a cost. Probably you are better without that.

Comment: @igracia my question is more of the scalability? Would I need a multi server setup?

Comment: for a single session, you won't need more than a single server. For multiple sessions, you definitely will need to have multiple servers. If you are fine with SaaS then go for TokBox - they have what you need "out of the box"